# Linq remove duplicate records as per column values C#

Tags: c#, linq, oop, lambda

I have a class `Items` with properties `Id, Name, Action`.

The list of `Items` is populated with duplicated items.

For example:

```
1     Item1    IT00001    Insert
2     Item1    IT00001    Delete
3     Item3    IT00003    Insert
4     Item4    IT00004    Update
```

How to remove the duplicates in the list using linq? so that my output will be

```
3     Item3    IT00003    Insert
4     Item4    IT00004    Update
```

Comment: can you show us what you have tried on your own thus far..? also why can't you write code that looks at Item / Action meaning Insert action is different than Delete Action therefore it's really not a duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with linq:

```
var filteredList = list.GroupBy(o => o.Name)
                       .Where(g => g.Count() == 1)
                       .SelectMany(g => g.Select(o => o))
                       .ToList();
```

Comment: Here, In above you have taken where the occurence is one only. But what if I need to remove those.

Comment: Simply change to `> 1`, then you will keep all the duplicates and filter out the unique items

Comment: sorry, not able to phrase q properly? If both records actions is same than I dont want to remove else your query is proper

Answer (score 0):

The code below returns a new list with distinct items in regard to the Name property:

```
    public class Test
    {
        public int Id;
        public string Name;
    }

    public class TestNameComparer : IEqualityComparer<Test>
    {
        public bool Equals(Test x, Test y)
        {
            if (x == null) return y == null;
            return x == y || string.Equals(x.Name, y.Name);
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Test obj)
        {
            return obj.Name.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

and the call:

```
        //List<Test> list = ...;
        var distinct = list.Distinct(new TestNameComparer());
```

So, depending on what property you want to consider (even multiple properties) when computing the distinct values, you change the IEqualityComparer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, But i want to remove those Items which have same name but more than one actions. So, In that case my output will not have items1 at all